# Creating a server socket in beaglebone

Tags: c, serversocket

I'm new in using beaglebone, and I need some help about some issues I'm facing.

I wrote a code in c (running in a laptop with ubuntu) in which a server socket is opened (running an apache server), and then another device connects to it through internet.

I would like to do the same in the beaglebone with ansgtrom distro (the one that comes with the board). I have read that angstrom distro comes with cloud9 (which from what I understand it acts as a server, like apache).

So, how can I create/open/use a server socket (through a program written in c) in cloud9-beaglebone?

Also, how can I configure cloud9 to store certain webpage? Is such configuration similar to the one in apache?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 IDE is an IDE for developing code for Node.JS.

The version of Node.JS used today is 0.6.20. There are examples on the nodejs.org home page and for the particular version at http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.20/.

To serve up web pages, I recommend you look into frameworks like ExpressJS. You can use the 'npm' utility under the Cloud9 IDE or the command line to install ExpressJS.

Since Cloud9 IDE allows you to edit C code, you can create typical C code that opens and serves sockets. pkg-config is installed to help you with linking libraries. You'll want to go to https://beaglebone.local to use Gate One to ssh into the board (username: root, password: ) and run the C compiler from the command line. You can use the same tools you'd use under Ubuntu, like 'make' and 'g++'.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I have a better idea about the whole system.